# Encontrar maior e menor valores únicos

Tags: python

Estou tentando encontrar o menor e o maior valor único de um array em Python, porém algo ainda está falho.

```
def pegaExtremosUnicos(v):
    i = 1
    for i in range(len(v)):
        atual = v[i]
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >=0) and (atual < v[j]):
            v[j +1] = v[j]
            j = j -1
        v[j + 1] = atual
    i = 1
    while i < len(v):
        if v[i] == v[i-1]:
            del v[i]
            del v[i-1]
        i = i +1
    d = [v[0],v[len(v)-1]]
    return tuple(d)
```

Qual foi o meu erro neste algorítimo?

Comment: Por que não usa o [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) e [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)?

Comment: Porque o `max` e `min` devem ser únicos

Comment: O que está falho? nesse teste parece que funciona: https://ideone.com/aFBwtd

Comment: Realizando alguns testes vi que em alguns casos, ele retorna números que repetiram.

Comment: Matheus mas não quer mesmo usar o 'min/max'? Ou é só porque eles retornariam valores repetidos (no caso de haver numeros max/min iguais na lista)? Para este ultimo caso, coloquei uma solução em baixo

Comment: Sua solução serviu Miguel. Obrigado

Comment: De nada Matheus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso dá para fazer mesmo usando max/min, tem é de definir o conjunto de valores em que vão atuar, neste caso não queremos incluir os elementos repetidos (ocorrências > 1) nesse conjunto:

```
vals = [123,4,5,4,6,7,8,300,200,150,300]
uniques = [i for i in vals if vals.count(i) < 2] # lista de todos os valores unicos de vals
max_value = max(uniques)
min_value = min(uniques)
print(max_value) # 200
print(min_value) # 5
```

Em que `vals.count(i)` vai contar o numero de ocorrências de `i` na lista `vals`. ex: `vals.count(300)` neste caso dá-nos `2`, ou seja nem entra na nossa nova lista `uniques`

PS: Testei o seu código que colocou e tal como o @zekk diz no comentário, também me parece que esteja a funcionar bem

Answer (score 2):

pode ser feito assim tbm:
import random

```
def valoresUnicos(lista):
    listaSemRepetidos = []
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista.count(lista[i]) == 1:
            listaSemRepetidos.append(lista[i])
    if listaSemRepetidos == []:
        return None, None
    else:
        return min(listaSemRepetidos), max(listaSemRepetidos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa para obter os elementos únicos é usar [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) para obter a contagem de cada elemento do array, e depois só verifique o maior e menor dentre aqueles cuja quantidade é `1`.

Outro detalhe é que usar [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) e depois [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) separadamente, apesar de funcionar, não é muito eficiente porque cada uma dessas funções percorre toda a lista, então você estará percorrendo todos os elementos duas vezes (uma para achar o menor, outra para achar o maior). Uma alternativa melhor seria percorrer apenas uma vez e verificar ambos no mesmo *loop*:

```
from collections import Counter

vals = [123, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 300, 200, 150, 300]
c = Counter(vals)
menor, maior = float('inf'), float('-inf')
for n, qtd in c.items():
    if qtd == 1:
        if n > maior:
            maior = n
        if n < menor:
            menor = n

print(f'menor={menor}, maior={maior}')
```

Outro detalhe é que as outras respostas estão usando `count` para verificar se o elemento não se repete. O problema é que cada chamada de `count` percorre toda a lista para obter a contagem daquele elemento, e isso é feito para cada elemento da lista. Ou seja, quando você faz isso:

```
[i for i in vals if vals.count(i) < 2]
```

Está percorrendo todos os elementos da lista, e para cada um deles, `count(i)` percorre a lista novamente para obter a contagem. Isso é extremamente redundante (ainda mais quando o elemento se repete várias vezes, pois fazemos a mesma contagem para ele várias vezes), além de bem ineficiente.

Quando você percorre várias vezes uma lista sem necessidade, está criando uma variação do chamado [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) (que é na verdade uma anedota para designar um algoritmo ruim).

Claro que para listas pequenas não fará tanta diferença assim (afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)), mas para listas maiores começa a dar problema. Veja um teste rápido feito com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), comparando os algoritmos das demais respostas:

```
from collections import Counter

def com_list_count(vals): # uma das respostas
    uniques = [i for i in vals if vals.count(i) < 2] # lista de todos os valores unicos de vals
    return max(uniques), min(uniques)

def com_list_count2(lista): # outra resposta
    listaSemRepetidos = []
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista.count(lista[i]) == 1:
            listaSemRepetidos.append(lista[i])
    if listaSemRepetidos == []:
        return None, None
    else:
        return max(listaSemRepetidos), min(listaSemRepetidos)

def com_counter(vals): # solução sugerida com Counter e um único loop em vez de usar min e max
    c = Counter(vals)
    menor, maior = float('inf'), float('-inf')
    for n, qtd in c.items():
        if qtd == 1:
            if n > maior:
                maior = n
            if n < menor:
                menor = n
    return maior, menor

from random import choices
# gerar uma lista com 10 mil números
# usar intervalo entre 10 e 999 para ter vários números repetidos
vals = choices(range(10, 1000), k=10000)
# adicionar números únicos (que não se repetem)
vals.extend([8, 2500, 3230, 4])

from timeit import timeit

# executa 5 vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 5, 'globals': globals() }

print(timeit('com_list_count(vals)', **params))
print(timeit('com_list_count2(vals)', **params))
print(timeit('com_counter(vals)', **params))
```

Eu criei uma lista com 10 mil números entre 10 e 999 (ou seja, com muitos valores repetidos). Depois adicionei alguns valores únicos (bastando usar valores fora deste intervalo).

Os tempos podem variar conforme o *hardware* e outros fatores, mas enfim, na minha máquina os tempos foram (em segundos):

```
7.6565183
7.7807781
0.0035252999999997314
```

Ou seja, as opções das outras respostas (que usam `count` para saber se o elemento se repete, além de chamar `min` e `max` separadamente) demoraram cerca de 2100 vezes mais, se comparado à solução com `Counter`. Também rodei em IDE's online e os resultados foram similares:

- [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zMpOMO) (tive que rodar apenas 1 vez ao invés de 5 para não estourar o limite de tempo): `Counter` foi cerca de 1400 vezes mais rápido
- [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/HoneydewGorgeousOutcomes#main.py): `Counter` foi mais de 7000 vezes mais rápido

Isso porque, como já explicado, cada chamada de `count` precisa percorrer a lista inteira novamente, para obter a contagem daquele elemento. E como isso é feito para todos os números da lista, isso torna o algoritmo extremamente ineficiente (e ainda tem o "bônus" de chamar `min` e `max` separadamente, que faz com que a lista ainda seja percorrida mais 2 vezes - mas o que faz "estrago" mesmo são as chamadas a `count` dentro do *loop*).

Por outro lado o `Counter` só precisa percorrer a lista uma vez e já contabiliza as quantidades de cada elemento. Depois só fazemos outro *loop* para descobrir o maior e menor. Por não percorrer a lista várias vezes, isso torna o algoritmo muito mais rápido.

Como já dito, para listas pequenas a diferença será insignificante. Mas para listas maiores, vale a pena ficar atento a esses detalhes.

Comment: Esta ganha hkotsubo's