# Criação de um vetor aleatorio

Tags: python-3.x, array

```
from random import randint # para gerar os nums aleatorios

def criaVetor(L, H, tam):
    vec = []
    for i in range(tam): # vamos fazer isto tam (N) vezes
        vec.append(randint(L, H)) # gerar numero aleatorio entre L e H, e colocar na nossa lista
    return vec


def pegaExtremosUnicos(vec):
    i = 1
    for i in range(len(vec)):
        atual = vec[i]
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >=0) and (atual < vec[j]):
            vec[j +1] = vec[j]
            j = j -1
        vec[j + 1] = atual
    i = 1
    while i < len(vec):
        if vec[i] == vec[i-1]:
            del vec[i]
            del vec[i-1]
        i = i +1
    d = [vec[0],vec[len(vec)-1]]
    return tuple(d)

vec = []
L = int(input('Informe o valor inteiro minimo da faixa:'))
H = int(input('Informe o valor inteiro maximo da faixa:'))
tam = int(input('Informe a quantidade de valores a serem sorteados:'))
print(criaVetor(L, H, tam))
print (pegaExtremosUnicos(criaVetor(L, H, tam)))
```

O que estaria errado?
Caso não existam valores mínimos ou máximos únicos, uma tupla de `None`’s deve ser retornada. Por exemplo:

- `[3, 5, 3, 10, 8]` retorna `(5, 10)` - retorno ok
- `[13]` retorna `(13, 13)`
  d = [vec[0],vec[len(vec)-1]]
  IndexError: list index out of range
- `[13, 13, 8, 8]` retorna `(None, None)`
  Informe o valor inteiro minimo da faixa:8
  Informe o valor inteiro maximo da faixa:13
  Informe a quantidade de valores a serem sorteados:4
  [10, 10, 12, 10]
  (9, 11)

Após retorno do subprograma, o programa principal deve exibir a tupla produzida.

Comment: ABSoares, deve colocar na pergunta que não pode random. É importante para quem o quer ajudar saber isso. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/148249/edit. Bem vindo ao stack overflow

Comment: Uma pergunta: porque tem de ser sem usar a função random? Qualquer maneira que se faça aqui é complexae muito extensa, e nem não se aproxima da eficácia dessa função

Comment: @Miguel hum... ok! Sou iniciante .......Continuando o que fizeste , como ficaria o item (c) ....cheguei a fazer algo , mas esta dando erro!

Comment: ?? Não percebi... Coloquei a minha resposta em baixo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que percebi todos os inputs do utilizador devem ser passados parametros ("...recebe como parâmetros o tamanho do vetor e a faixa de valores."):

```
from random import randint # para gerar os nums aleatorios

def criaVetor(L, H, tam):
    vec = []
    for i in range(tam): # vamos fazer isto tam (N) vezes
        vec.append(randint(L, H)) # gerar numero aleatorio entre L e H, e colocar na nossa lista
    return vec

L = int(input('Informe o valor inteiro minimo da faixa:'))
H = int(input('Informe o valor inteiro maximo da faixa:'))
tam = int(input('Informe a quantidade de valores a serem sorteados:'))
print(criaVetor(L, H, tam))
```

Comment: Preciso continuar o que fizeste! 

c) Via subprograma, buscar o menor () e o maior () valores únicos (isto é, que não se repetem) contidos no vetor. O subprograma deve receber como parâmetro apenas o vetor e retornar tais valores em uma tupla no formato (, ). Caso não existam valores mínimos ou máximos únicos, uma tupla de None’s deve ser retornada. Por exemplo: [3, 5, 3, 10, 8] retorna (5, 10) [13] retorna (13, 13) [13, 13, 8, 8] retorna (None, None) Após retorno do subprograma, o programa principal deve exibir a tupla produzida.

Comment: @ABSoares Sobre obter o *menor* e o *maior* valor do vetor, veja essa resposta do Miguel: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145998/6454

Comment: @Miguel ta dando erro ao rodar os testes a funçãominmax

def minmax(L, H): 
Por exemplo: [3, 5, 3, 10, 8] retorna (5, 10) [13] retorna (13, 13) [13, 13, 8, 8] retorna (None, None)

Comment: Essa função é suposto fazer o quê? @ABSoares

Comment: def minmax(L, H): vec = [] i = 1 for i in range(len(vec)): atual = vec[i] j = i - 1 while (j >=0) and (atual < vec[j]): vec[j +1] = vec[j] j = j -1 vec[j + 1] = atual i = 1 while i < len(vec): if vec[i] == vec[i-1]: del vec[i] del vec[i-1] i = i +1 d = [vec[0],vec[len(vec)-1]] return tuple(d) print (minmax(L, H))

Comment: Eu assim não percebo @ABSoares, diga o que é que essa função é suposto fazer, já vi que recebe os dois valores (min, max) e depois? O que vai fazer com eles

Comment: buscar o menor () e o maior () valores únicos (isto é, que não se repetem) contidos no vetor. Deverá receber como parâmetro apenas o vetor e retornar tais valores em uma tupla no formato (, ). Caso não existam valores mínimos ou máximos únicos, uma tupla de None’s deve ser retornada. Por exemplo:
[3, 5, 3, 10, 8] retorna (5, 10)
[13] retorna (13, 13)
[13, 13, 8, 8] retorna (None, None)
Após retorno do subprograma, o programa principal deve exibir a tupla produzida.